# What do you call a female Chosid?

Tags: hebrew, women, chasidut-hasidism, language, yiddish

I have encountered a lot of different words purporting to be the feminine version of Chosid (Hasid/Hassid/חסיד). I have seen or heard:

- Chosides (~Chosidit?)
- Chasideh/Chasida
- Most recently, "Chassidiste."

Which, if any, of these is correct? If none, is something else correct? If there is no "correct" term, what term is most widely used?

---

I'm asking primarily about the modern usage of Chosid but would also be interested to know if the mishneh had a word for the feminine version of what it called Chosid.

Comment: I wouldn't use chasida

Comment: @Danno because of the Righteous Bird or for some other reason?

Comment: No matter how righteous, I shan't be calling a woman a bird (or a chick...)

Comment: none of the above. best to call people by their actually name rather than by a label.

Comment: חסידקע / chasidke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Comprehensive English-Yiddish Dictionary](http://www.iupress.indiana.edu/product_info.php?cPath=6040_6061&products_id=808200) has

> Hasid, *f.* --- די חסידה, ־ות; די חסידתטע, ־ס

with pronunciations [KhSÍDE, -S] and [KhSÍDESTE, -S], respectively.

Comment: @SAH I don't understand your comment.  The dictionary I quoted gives two translations, and I gave two pronunciations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39368/discussion-between-magicker72-and-sah).

Answer (score 1):

Chossidit is an adjective, not a name. But Chassidist is a name. In Hebrew this name is Chassida. In Erets Israel we say Chassida. But Litayt, not Litaa. (mnemonic: Storks eat lizards, so we say litait because of the Chassida).